# Proxy Number instance in js

Tags: javascript, object

I have a task to implement expression 0..II to return [0, 1, 2] (same for all Roman numerals).

I have looked up Proxy object concept and this works fine.

```js
var handler = {
 get: function(obj, prop) {
  console.log(prop);
  x = parseRomanNumeral(prop);
  if (x) {
   return Array.from(Array(x).keys());
  }

 },
 defineProperty: function(target, property, descriptor) {
  console.log('1');
 }
}

var target = {};
var proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);
console.log(proxy.II); //[0, 1]
```

But I don't understand how to do the same with the expression 0..I as 0. is the instance of Number. What should I pass to Proxy constructor?

Comment: are you looking for something like proxy['0']?

Answer (score 2):

The expression `0..II` actually means accessing `II` property on `Number.prototype`, since first dot is decimal while second is property accessor. For example:

`console.log(0..toString()) // => '0'`

So, I believe you're looking for combination of [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) and [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)
Consider the following code

```js
Object.setPrototypeOf(
  Number.prototype, 
  new Proxy(Number.prototype, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if(prop === 'II') {
        return [0, 1, 2]
      }
      else {
        return target[prop]
      }
    }
  }))
  
  console.log(0..II)  // [0, 1, 2]
```

While this can do the trick, I don't think extending primitives prototypes is a good idea, since it makes your code much less maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `proxy['0..II']`. The properties given to an object can be of three kinds: numbers, strings and symbols. Numeric values are also given as strings to the proxy handler, so `proxy[1]` gives `"1"` (and not `1`) as the property.

Doing `proxy.II` is, indeed, the same as doing `proxy['II']`.